# Debian circular dependency with required packages

Tags: debian, apt, system-installation, dpkg

I am building a rootfs manually (without `debootstrap` or `multistrap`) for various reasons that I won't get into.

I am extracting the required debs to the rootfs (using `dpkg` with custom `--instdir` and `--admindir`) in an "unpacked" state. I plan on to later chroot into the system and run `dpkg --configure <packagename>` for each package on topological order.

There are two required (`Priority: required`) packages needed for a fresh install of Debian, `libc6` ([here](https://packages.debian.org/buster/libgcc1)) and `libgcc1` ([here](https://packages.debian.org/buster/libc6)). They both have a hard requirement on each other.

Because of this, I can't run `dpkg --configure <packagename>` on one package because it complains that the other package is still in an "unpacked" state that needs to be configured.

Dead lock. And it makes sense.

How is this possible? How does the standard Ubuntu/Debian installer ISOs handle this?

In the mean time, I am running `dpkg --configure -a`, and it seems to configure every package correctly, but I'm not exactly sure how it is doing it, and the topological order it chooses to configure the package is incorrect.

Ideally, I'd like a stage 2 script that runs the preinst script for each package and then configures that package alone. Something like this.

```bsh
# Optional, if the preinst exists for the package.
DPKG_MAINTSCRIPT_NAME=preinst DPKG_MAINTSCRIPT_ARCH=amd64 DPKG_MAINTSCRIPT_PACKAGE=apt /var/lib/dpkg/info/<packagename>.preinst install
# Required, for every package.
dpkg --configure <packagename>
# ...repeated for each package, in topological order.
```

The way `debootstrap` and `multistrap` work around this is that they don't use `dpkg` to do the configuring. They manually run preinst/postinst and update the `/var/lib/dpkg/status` db, but each script have their own issues that I won't get into.

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrapping a Debian system is outside the realms of Debian policy. The mechanics are currently encoded in the various bootstrappers, to include all implicit information that is otherwise not present in the packages, such as dependencies between Essential:yes packages. This is a problem because we need to duplicate all this in every new bootstrapper, and it is fragile as changes to the pseudo-essential package set might break those assumptions.

We are trying to improve this at https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/Dpkg/Spec/InstallBootstrap. You might want to check out mmdebstrap which tries to use stock tools and offload as much as possible to them, and to the package metadata, so in a way it's the PoC implementation for the above proposal.

I'd recommend using mmdebstrap, but if that's not an option, and you are still trying to reimplement a bootstrapper, you'd probably want to check the source of various existing bootstrappers to get at these implicit details.